# How would one write a dynamic word document using query results, excel and word

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I've been tasked with coming up with an approach to use query results to write a dynamic paragraph or two in word.  The subject matter is financial and the paragraph will take the form of the following example:

Net sales *increased* [000] or [000]%. This compares to the prior period when sales were [ ].  Operating profit *increased* by [00]% or $[00] to [00]. The *increase* was fueled by...

The data include the brackets would come directly from the query results. Words like increased could or should also be dynamic, reflecting the values in the query.

Possible approaches:

1. One approach I have considered is to set up a mailmerge document with fields and map the query result to the document and simple merged the query result into the mailmerge document.  This approach does well with the bracket data but I'm not quite sure how it would do with the increase/decreases.
2. A second approach would be to use Excels text() function and concatenation to dynamically create the sentences and paragraphs and then perform a copy past special before copying to a word document.
3. A third approach might be to use Excel VBA to write the document, but this has the potential to get very involved.

Have others come across a similar task?  If so, how did you solve this problem?  Just trying to get some fresh ideas on how to tackle this.  I work primarily in Excel, perhaps Word has some features that lend themselves well to this challenge.

Comment: for quickest/easiest - I'd add a calc'ed column to hold the "dynamic" text (without the "d"), and mail merge (the "d" can be hardcoded where needed - so the calc column would hold "increase".  NOTE: if you need other forms (capitalization, etc) then a code-based approach may be necessary, if you don't want to add columns for all needed permutations. (increase, increased, Increase, Increased, etc)

Comment: If you use mailmerge you could handle increase/decrease in a couple of ways. (a) Use merge fields for the occurrences of increase/decrease. (b) The mail merge supports if-then-else logic, so when the change in sales < 0 you can have the merge insert "decreased". For example `{ IF { MERGEFIELD SalesChange } > 0 "increased" "decreased" }`